# Accounting for autocorrelation in predictive models?

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, prediction, autocorrelation, validation

**Is it necessary to account for autocorrelation of data in a predictive model?**

I ask because it seems that accounting for autocorrelation (temporal or spatial) by means of ACF, PCF, etc. is typically performed to better understand (*isolate*?) the actual effects (correlation) that an independent variable has on some response.

However, if I'm creating a model for the sole purpose of ***prediction*** (and likely choosing the "best" model based primarily on model performance), does accounting for underlying correlation structure really matter??

- Does accounting for autocorrelation improve the predictability of my model in any way?
- Is it instead perhaps standard operating procedure for modelers to examine autocorrelation anyway just to confirm that their other variables belong in the model to begin with?

  - Or is model performance really all that's important here?

Comment: From a statistician's perspective, you should always account for autocorrelation. A reason you may care about autocorrelation is because it can give you biased parameter estimates meaning your predictions may not be as accurate as they could be!

Comment: @Jon, forecasting is about trade-offs. Accounting for autocorrelation may or may not pay out; it depends on how strong it is. This is analogous to how you may gain forecast accuracy by omitting statistically significant variables from the model. So the answer to the OP's question is not entirely clear cut.

Comment: Treating the data as if it were iid would not benefit you if autocorrelation is strong. You'd want to take advantage of the autocorrelation to make better predictions as the data is not uniformly distributed.

Comment: Do you have any specific type of model/prediction in mind? Note that a common reason models "account for autocorrelation" is to "predict a variable from *itself*" (e.g. many applications of [tag:arima] and [tag:gaussian-process]). The OP seems perhaps to be thinking of more "predictor vs. dependent" variables? (and *not* considering lagged/shifted versions of a dependent variable to be potential predictors?)

Comment: I have repeated measures tree growth data (diameter and height) for ~100,000 trees tracked through time (~80years). Some trees are missing height measures, so I'm attempting to create a model using my data (via cross validation) to predict the missing heights. The main predictor is diameter, but I'm assuming that categorical "structural" predictors such as species, plot location, and individual tree ID needs to be taken into account through random effects or other approach as well. I'm not sure if temporal autocorrelation needs to be additionally examined...

Comment: http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/bouriaud.pdf might be of interest to you as it descibes how AUTOBOX was succesfully used for tree ring data analysis dating back to 1990.

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is to forecast or predict, then the answer is a resounding "it depends." If autocorrelation is strong, then including it will likely improve your forecasts.

However, modeling autocorrelation means we need to estimate more parameters. If autocorrelation is weak, then the bias-variance tradeoff tells us that beyond some model complexity, we may be better off *not* modeling it.

This can be extended to higher order autocorrelations. With infinite data of an AR(5) process, modeling this as AR(5) will indeed give you lowest expected squared errors... but in a world of finite data, it may well be that fitting an AR($p$) model with $p<5$ yields lower errors. Similarly for MA($q$) dynamics.

In addition, you may well have predictors that capture autoregressive behavior. Are your daily retail sales AR(7), or is this just intra-weekly seasonality, which can be captured using days of the week? If the latter, you might be able to improve your forecasts by combining days that behave similarly, e.g., treating all of Monday to Thursday as the same.